# Как отобрать срез строк со смещением?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, обработка-данных

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'фрукт': ['авокадо','груша','арбуз', 'груша', 'вишня', 'груша', 'банан'],
'страна': ['китай','сша', np.nan, np.nan,'канада',  np.nan, 'перу'],
'id': ['01','01','01', '011', '011',  '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['март','январь','январь', 'февраль', 'февраль', 'апрель', 'апрель']
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно для каждой группы по `id` получить одну строку в результате. Эта строка должна содержать значение фрукта из последней строки в группе, а значения страны и месяца из предпоследней строки в группе.

Ожидаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это ведь учебное задание? И что вы уже пытались сами сделать? Вообще мне смутно напоминает один вопрос, на который я недавно отвечал. `groupby`, `shift`, `index` и всё такое...

Comment: Это не учебное задание, я не могу показать реальные данные. Поэтому придумал сам такой фрейм. 
Вы правы, очень похоже на shift, но не то же самое. По крайней мере, я не смог понять. Помогите пожалуйста @CrazyElf

Comment: @MaxU Я сейчас активно тестирую, не всегда получается. Пытаюсь разобраться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .assign(страна=df["страна"].shift(), месяц=df["месяц"].shift())
       .groupby("id")
       .last()
       .reset_index())
```

или более гибкий вариант

```
cols = ["страна", "месяц"]

res = (df
       .drop(columns=cols)
       .join(df[cols].shift())
       .groupby("id")
       .last()
       .reset_index())
```

результат:

```
In [92]: res
Out[92]: 
    id  фрукт  страна    месяц
0   01  арбуз     сша   январь
1  011  вишня     NaN  февраль
2    5  банан  канада   апрель
```

---

или так если нужно именно предпоследние значения, включая `NaN`'s:

```
In [108]: res = (df
     ...:        .assign(страна=df["страна"].shift(), месяц=df["месяц"].shift())
     ...:        .groupby("id", dropna=False)
     ...:        .nth(-1)
     ...:        .reset_index())

In [109]: res
Out[109]: 
    id  фрукт страна    месяц
0   01  арбуз    сша   январь
1  011  вишня    NaN  февраль
2    5  банан    NaN   апрель
```

Comment: с аргументом dropna=False выдет ошибку. Как можно это обойти? group() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dropna'

Comment: В рамках https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1238732/255714 можете рассматривать