# Срез строк в группе внутри группы

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','груша','вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша','арбуз','груша','банан','груша', 'груша', 'вишня','яблоко', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'груша', 'банан'],
'страна': ['россия','сша', 'россия','россия', 'франция','ЮАР','франция', 'россия', np.nan, np.nan,'россия','андорра', 'франция', 'португалия', 'россия', np.nan, np.nan, 'россия'],
'id': ['01','01','01','01','01','01','01','011', '011', '011', '011','011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['март','сентябрь','январь','сентябрь', 'апрель','июль','октябрь', 'сентябрь', 'январь', 'сентябрь', 'январь','январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'сентябрь', 'май', 'апрель']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно, для группы `id` выделить все строки, где `месяц == сенятбрь`. Далее, нужно значение из колонки `фрукт` строки группы `id`, следующей после последней записи, где `месяц = сентябрь` соединить со значениями `страна, id, месяц` из последней строки внутри группы `id`, где значение `месяц = сентябрь`.

Как можно это сделать?

На первом скриншоте можно увидеть механику работы.

Ожидаемый результат выделен на скриншоте

Comment: Раз вы изменили ошиблись с условием, то поправте пожлуйста и ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ответ на измененный вопрос:

```
res = (df
       .assign(фрукт=df.groupby("id")["фрукт"].shift(-1))
       .query("месяц == 'сентябрь'")
       .groupby("id")
       .nth(-1)
       .reset_index())
```

результат:

```
In [59]: res
Out[59]:
    id  фрукт  страна     месяц
0   01  груша  россия  сентябрь
1  011  вишня     NaN  сентябрь
2    5  груша     NaN  сентябрь
```

Comment: А как я могу использовать query , если вместо "сентябрь" потребуется указать переменную со строковым значением, которое может содержать другой месяц?

Comment: @formanite, `.query("месяц == @variable_name")` - обратите внимание на "@"

Answer (score 2):

```
res = (df
       .loc[df.reset_index().query("месяц == 'сентябрь'")
              .groupby("id")["index"].last()])

res = (res
       .drop(columns="фрукт")
       .merge(df.groupby("id")["фрукт"].last().reset_index()))
```

результат:

```
In [30]: res
Out[30]:
   страна   id     месяц  фрукт
0  россия   01  сентябрь  арбуз
1     NaN  011  сентябрь  вишня
2     NaN    5  сентябрь  банан
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, при составлении фрейма не учел, что после строк со значением месяца = сентябрь может быть больше одной строки. И тогда нужнo брать не последнюю строку из группы id, а брать строку, следующую после послдней строки со значением месяца = сентябрь в группе id

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, первый скриншот. Я его обновил

Comment: @formanite, а если не существует записи "следующей после последней записи, где месяц = сентябрь" ??

Comment: тогда либо пропускать такие кейсы, либо, если удобнее, заполнять такие кейсы фруктом = "пусто"
Где "пусто" обычный строковый объект